# Count continuously repeated nan in the list or array by groupby

Tags: python

This is related to my previous question long time ago.
I would like to count nan from the list, but it is not string but real nan such as.

```
b = [1.0, nan, nan, 3.5 ...]
```

From this list, I would like to count the lenth of continuous nan. In the case above the number would be 2.

My code was:

```
 v = [len(list(group)) for key, group in groupby(b) if key== np.isnan(key)]
```

In this case the result of v turns out empty.

Also when I changed code to:

```
  v = [len(list(group)) for key, group in groupby(b) if key== np.isnan(b)]
```

The error occurs as ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all().

Would you please give me any idea or help?

Comment: What if the list is `[1.0, nan, nan, 3.5, nan, nan, nan]`?

Comment: `groupby` takes a `key` argument representing what you want to group the input by. Use that.

Comment: @aj8uppal, I would like to get 2 and 3 which is the number for two groups of consequent nan.

Comment: @user2357112 Do you mean such as if key==nan? It didn't work.

Comment: It's an *argument*. I'm not talking about the return value. `groupby(b, key=np.isnan)` groups the elements of `b` by whether or not they're NaNs. See DSM's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
v = [len(list(group)) for key, group in groupby(b) if key== np.isnan(key)]
```

You're comparing `key`, which is an element of the list, to `np.isnan(key)`, which is a boolean.  Moreover, since `nan != nan`, this might not even group neighbouring nans together.

```
v = [len(list(group)) for key, group in groupby(b) if key== np.isnan(b)]
```

Now you're comparing `key`, which is an element of the list, to an entire boolean numpy array.  That isn't what you want to do either, and `numpy` is quite reasonably telling you that there's no canonical way for it to know what you want `bool(key == np.isnan(b))` to do, so it can't figure out whether or not to take the `if`.

Maybe something like

```
>>> b = np.array([1, np.nan, np.nan, 2, 3, np.nan, 4])
>>> v = [len(list(group)) for key, group in groupby(b, key=np.isnan) if key]
>>> v
[2, 1]
```

would work.  The individual parts will look something like

```
>>> vv = [(key, list(group)) for key, group in groupby(b, key=np.isnan)]
>>> vv
[(False, [1.0]), (True, [nan, nan]), (False, [2.0, 3.0]), (True, [nan]), (False, [4.0])]
```

(With a bit more thought you could probably get a vectorized numpy approach to work too, but let's start with the tools you're familiar with.)

---

As @user2357112 notes in the comments, since we only care about the length of the nan clusters, we can optimize this by doing the `isnan` check all in one go:

```
>>> b
array([  1.,  nan,  nan,   2.,   3.,  nan,   4.])
>>> np.isnan(b)
array([False,  True,  True, False, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
>>> [len(list(g)) for k,g in groupby(np.isnan(b)) if k]
[2, 1]
```

Comment: For a start on the vectorized approach, it'd make sense to pass `np.isnan(b)` to the grouping logic instead of using `key=np.isnan`, which will call `isnan` on each element separately.

Comment: You can also use [ilen](http://funcy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/seqs.html#ilen) from [funcy](https://github.com/Suor/funcy) library instead of `len(list(...))` for speed.

Comment: @Suor: or just `sum(1 for _ in g)`, but to be honest I tend to cross such bridges when I come to them.

Comment: @DSM `ilen` implementation is more efficient than that, but sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the following:

```
>>> from numpy import nan
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> x = [1.0, nan, nan, 3.5, nan, nan, nan]
>>> [item[1] for item in [(c,len(list(cgen))) for c,cgen in groupby(x)] if item[0] is nan]
[2, 3]
>>>
```

This uses `groupby` and then gets all the occurrences.

Comment: This doesn't work. First, `is nan` isn't how you check whether something is a NaN. It is not required or expected that all NaNs are the `np.nan` object. Second, `groupby(x)` doesn't group NaNs correctly, since NaNs aren't equal to each other. Third, the list comprehension looping over another list comprehension is unnecessarily confusing. You could remove the inner comprehension entirely and just change `item[1]` a bit to get the same effect.

Comment: To see the `nan != nan` problem, try replacing the `nan`s in `x` with `float("nan")` instead.